# Windows Server 2016 Standard: User accounts filling up C: drive, but the accounts are empty

Tags: storage, windows-server-2016

I'm dealing with a virtual server that keeps maxing out the C: drive due to the Users directory.  The Users directory has well over 2,000 Users, each taking up ~70MB of space, but when I look in an individual User directory I find that the total space allocation (sum of all directories in the screenshot below) should only be around 4MB.

Is this expected behavior for the Users' dir and do I need to perform a cleanup of the directory itself?  If not, is there a way I can find what is making these dirs so large?  This server is used as a Citrix host so I know for a fact that some of the "Users" are not actually using their accounts directly.

[image: Individual User Directory Example]

Comment: Your Windows Explorer is not showing hidden files. If you only checked the size of the visible directories, you are potentially missing a lot of information. A tool like [WizTree](https://diskanalyzer.com/) is going to be much more useful than manually checking directory sizes.